# FireMonkey: how to suppress default popup menu

Tags: delphi, popup, firemonkey

I've got a TMemo with an associated TPopupMenu on a FireMonkey form.

When I rightclick on the memo, I get my own popup menu, but after my popup disappears I still get the default popup (the one that says cut, copy, paste, select all).

How do I disable the default menu, or can I add my own items to the default menu perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't reproduce this behavior. Here's what I tried:

- `File->New->FireMonkey HD Application`
- Drop a `TMemo` and `TPopupMenu` on the form
- Assign `PopupMenu` to `Memo1.PopupMenu` in the Object Inspector
- Create two menu items in the `PopupMenu`, and assign them both the same `OnClick` event (generated in the Object Inspector). I left the default caption of  `MenuItem1` and `MenuItem2` in the `Caption` of both items.
- Wrote a simple `MessageDlg` that displays `TMenuItem(Sender).Caption` with a single `Ok` button in the `OnClick` handler.
- Run the application, right-click `Memo1`, and choose either menu item

I get a single menu displayed with my two items (`MenuItem1` and `MenuItem2`). Choosing either item displays the appropriate `Caption` in a message dialog, and clicking `Ok` in that dialog. There is no default popup menu displayed.

**EDIT**: Found it for you. This is a bug fixed in Update 3 - see the [list of bug fixes in Update 3](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41831/), and search for `98705`, or scroll through until you reach the section on `FireMonkey\Components` (it's the second or third entry under that section).

Comment: I just did exactly what you did, but I still get the default popup no matter what I do. I'm using XE2 update2. Maybe this is a bug and it was fixed in update 3 or 4? Are you using any of those?

Comment: I have Update 3 (there have been reports of issues with 4, so I'm holding off on it right now).

Comment: Anyway, +1 for trying the steps that you've described. I just wanted to verify that I'm not crazy. No definite answer to that yet :)  I should just bite the bullet and upgrade to 3 (rumours about issues with 4 are enough to keep me away for now).

Comment: I'm thinking those reports are of good value. I attempted to walk your steps and I can't even compile `MessageDlg('..',mtWarning,..` (*'Undeclared identifier: 'mtWarning'*). I have to write `MessageDlg('..',TMsgDlgType(0),..`. I can't duplicate the problem either BTW.

Comment: @Sertac, that's a change in XE2 (as you know). Here's what you need: `  MessageDlg('You chose ' + TMenuItem(Sender).Text, TMsgDlgType.mtConfirmation,      [TMsgDlgBtn.mbOk], 0);`.

Comment: Ah! I wasn't aware of that since the regular VCL still accepts the other way around. Stupid me! Thanks @Ken.